# How to display output in single line

Tags: c#, arrays, console

My program is generating an output, but I am expecting a different output than what is generated.
If I send 6 input numbers, it should compare the numbers and generate an answer.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

class Solution 
{
    static void Main(String[] args) 
    {
        string[] tokens_a0 = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        
        int a0 = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_a0[0]);
        int a1 = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_a0[1]);
        int a2 = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_a0[2]);
        
        string[] tokens_b0 = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        
        int b0 = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_b0[0]);
        int b1 = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_b0[1]);
        int b2 = Convert.ToInt32(tokens_b0[2]);
        
        if (a0 > b0 || a0 < b0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(1);
        }
        if (a1 > b1 || a1 < b1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(1);
        }
        if (a2 > b2 || a2 < b2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(1);
        }
    }
}
```

The code above is generating the following output:

> 1
>
> 1

I need the output to display like this instead:

> 1 1

How can I change the code to generate the output in this manner?

Comment: what loop?! Have you tried reading the manual on Console.WriteLine? Have you looked for other output methods that might help you get what you want? Have you put any effort into solving your own problem?

Comment: Your `if` statements are checking if one number is either greater than or less than the second number...you could shorten your `if` statements (and make your code easier to read) if you replaced it with a check to see if the numbers are not equal instead. For example, the `if (a0 > b0 || a0 < b0)` statment can be changed to `if (a0 != b0)`.

Comment: Console.WriteLine "Writes the specified data, followed by the current line terminator, to the standard output stream." In other words writes the specified text to a new line in the console. Therefore the output cannot be on the same line with multiple statements. A single statement is the only way. Plus, as @Sylverac has mentioned, your code is inefficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Console.WriteLine` does exactly what the name says, it writes your message, followed by a new line.

If you want your output to be in the same line, you should use `Console.Write`:

```
if (a0 > b0 || a0 < b0)
{
   Console.Write(1 + " ");
}
if (a1 > b1 || a1 < b1)
{
    Console.Write(1 + " ");
}
if (a2 > b2 || a2 < b2)
{
    Console.Write(1 + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are suggesting `Console.Write`, and they're all correct. I just want to add another way to produce the result you're looking for that might allow a bit more control over the final output, should you find it useful.

```
        string message = "";
        if (a0 > b0 || a0 < b0)
        {
            message += "1";
        }
        if (a1 > b1 || a1 < b1)
        {
            message += "1";
        }
        if (a2 > b2 || a2 < b2)
        {
            message += "1";
        }
        //make any further modifications to the result here, if needed
        Console.WriteLine(message);
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use Console.Write() along with a space character instead of Console.WriteLine().

```
if (a0 > b0 || a0 < b0)
   {
    Console.Write(1 + " ");
}
if (a1 > b1 || a1 < b1)
{
    Console.Write(1 + " ");
}
if (a2 > b2 || a2 < b2)
{
    Console.Write(1 + " ");
}
```

WriteLine() will insert a newline after the outputted text.

Check out the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx) for information on Console.WriteLine() and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.write(v=vs.110).aspx) for information on Console.Write().